# issue related to jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

which expression should i use to extract the numeric value from the following line of code in the response of the recording.
 please help

```
URL = URL + "documentId="+78556;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding an integer value it is always preferred to use "(\d)" i.e. Integer type regex. Though (.+?) will also match but if chances of matching other similar regex are possible. To avoid such misfindings use below regex.

```
documentId=\"\+(\d+);
```

Rest values in Regular expression extractor should be same.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are expecting numerical value from *"URL = URL + "documentId="+78556;"*

**Regular Expression:**  .documentId="\+(.+?);

Result will be ***"78556"***

Hope this will help